# How to set a Twitter account to automatically retweet another account?

Tags: twitter, tweets

How can I set a Twitter account to automatically retweet another account?

For example, if there was a main business account with three subsidiary business accounts below it and the main account wishes to retweet all of the subsidiary tweets.

It would be great if this could be set in Tweetdeck (where one can do this manually).

Additionally, functionality based on keywords could be useful.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "automatically". You could write a program that periodically downloads the timeline of the 1st account and retweets the subsidiary tweets. In that program you could use keywords too. But, more seriously, there is not such a feature in any library that I know of.

Comment: By "automatically" I mean to retweet every tweet on its own, as soon as possible.

Comment: Well, I guess you could run your program very often. There is no other automatic way.

Comment: But I think twice about it and if you run it too frequently you'll face Twitter rate limits... Sorry that I'm not being of much help.

Comment: That's ok, I like your brainstorming. For now I will just do this manually with TweetDeck. Perhaps this is better anyways, as it keeps me more in the loop.